# Scraping with php (simple html Dom)

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to make a web scraper with php however I am a bit stuck, although I found simple html Dom all the instructions I follow don't work, and seem a bit outdated. I was wondering if there is a better way of doing it nowadays and why is it not working for me. I have the following code in php,:

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$title = $html->find('title', 0);
$image = $html->find('img', 0);

echo $title->plaintext."<br>\n";
echo $image->src;
```

I do not have a document called 'simple_html_dom.php'. Im not sure if that is a document or not that I need but I couldn't find it either way.

As you can probably tell I am a complete beginner in php scraping, so all help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you should download the required files first: https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

Comment: @Andreas that doesn’t really help. Where should the files go?

Comment: Extract the files in the folder where the .php file you posted is located and try again.